# How to set session variables for guest users only in Yii?

Tags: php, session, yii

I want to set a session array variable for only guests users in Yii. I want that when the user runs the application an array should be created for him in session. Later I need that session array to push values to it when user adds items to the cart. The problem is I can't figure out where do I set that session variable?

I know if the user is being logged in then I can set that in User Identity using authenticate function:

```
$this->setState('cart',array());
```

or

```
Yii::app()->user->setState('cart',array());
```

But that works when the user logs in and authentication function is called. In my case the user will not login and will go to product purchase page where that session array should be available.

Any ideas?
Please comment if further information is needed.

Comment: To reduce duplicated logic i would be tempted to always have a user, 'guest' or 'real' and check for authentication when processing the cart. Give the 'guest' a unique user id that you keep in the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use the session directly? You do not have to use the setState for the Yii::app()->user to keep the cart. Just do a

```
Yii::app()->session['cart'] = array();
```

It does not matter if the user is logged in or not, he still has a session. Then just update Yii::app()->session['cart'].

That is what I do anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I thought of same solution.

Comment: @Hammad, I thought of it as a real person filling a cart - then going to the checkout. You now need a 'user' to process the payment against. But you already have that logic in place

Comment: I thought about that too, to use the Yii::app()->user to keep the cart in. But when a guest user goes to the website, adds things in the cart and then logs in, I believe the Yii::app()->user would change. So you would have to save the cart someplace else then tie it back to the user after he logs in, isn't that correct? So why not just keep it someplace else to begin with.

Comment: @Mihai, i haven't used Yii so your way sounds as useful.

Answer (score 0):

if use

```
Yii::app()->session['cart'] = array();
```

error "Indirect modification of overloaded element of CDbHttpSession has no effect"

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/4262-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-session/

Comment: hmm, i use \Yii::app()->session['cart'.$this->key] = $cart; and it works fine, but $cart is an object not an array.